# Индекс mysql. Найти не соответствующие id из двух таблиц (большая БД)

Tags: mysql, sql

Прочитал про создание индексов в mySql, подскажите как будет правильнее создать. Задача такая: "Если id из таблицы post_phones.post_id нет в таблице post.post_id, то вывести эти id (из этой таблицы post_phones.post_id)." Ниже написан запрос, который я использую:

```
SELECT `post_phones`.`post_id`
FROM `post_phones`
LEFT JOIN `post` 
ON (`post_phones`.`post_id` = `post`.`id_post`) 
WHERE `post`.`id_post`IS NULL 
LIMIT 1000;
```

В начале он показал себя очень хорошо, но когда id в таблице `post_phones` достигли 13 млн, сервер начал долго грузится. Я хочу создать индекс для таблиц. Вопрос, какой из создания индексов подойдёт для решения моей задачи, и вообще,  сработает ли данная идея?

```
CREATE INDEX id_post ON post(id_post);
```

или

```
CREATE INDEX post_id ON post_phones(post_id);
```

И нужно ли использовать `ORDER BY`?

Comment: боюсь, индексы здесь делу не помогут... я бы сделал из `post_phones.post_id` нормальный внешний ключ с `ON DELETE SET NULL` или `ON DELETE CASCADE`... если так нельзя по условию, то придётся городить что-то из вычислимых столбцов...

Comment: * s/вычислимых столбцов/видов/

Comment: Нужны ОБА индекса, по обеим таблицам. Тогда, возможно, они и станут использоваться - надо смотреть план. Один индекс - это ниачём. *нужно ли использовать ORDER BY?* При наличии LIMIT запрос без ORDER BY - это гадание на костях.

Comment: @Akina, а как будет верно в моём запросе написать `ORDER BY`? Мне бы искать с самых больших id в каждой таблице, можете помочь?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ваше решение очень интересное, вы могли бы на реальном примере показать как это делается?

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха ORDER BY включается в работу только тогда, когда запрос выполнен и все записи для вывода получены. Он только расположит их в нужном порядке.

Comment: @Akina, понял, значит скорость выполнения запроса это не изменит

Comment: @Akina, а если добавить 2 индекса они повлияют на работу с этими таблицами в других скриптах?

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха *скорость выполнения запроса это не изменит* Это с чего бы? сортировка-то - она не мгновенная... *если добавить 2 индекса они повлияют на работу с этими таблицами в других скриптах?* А как же... обязательно повлияют. Только не спрашивай как именно - у меня ХШ в ремонте.

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха, про внешние ключи написал в ответ, а про вычислимые столбцы и про виды — это не жизнеспособные идеи...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал из `post_phones.post_id` нормальный *внешний ключ* (`FOREIGN KEY`)

```
ALTER TABLE post_phones
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post (id_post) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Из того о чём следует помнить при таком подходе:

- Это запретит добавление новых записей ссылающихся на несуществующие `post_id`
- Перед добавлением ограничения все такие записи надо предварительно удалить или установить в `NULL`.

  ```
  UPDATE post_phones SET post_id = NULL 
  WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT id_post FROM post WHERE id=post_id);
  ```
- При удалении записи из таблицы `post` все значения в полях с соответствующем `post_phones.post_id` будут установлены в `NULL`.
- При наличии индекса по `post_phones.post_id` (должен быть неявно создан при добавлении внешнего ключа) данные с удалёнными соответствующими записями из `post` можно выбирать простым запросом практически моментально (на самом деле за логарифмическое время с большим показателем) время:

  ```
  SELECT post_id FROM post_phones
  WHERE post_id IS NULL
  ```
- Также можно использовать `ON DELETE CASCADE` — в таком случае при удалении записи из `post` будут удаляться и все связанные с оной записи из `post_phones`
- Хорошей мыслью также будет добавить `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, дабы всё было когерентно, если кто-то вручную захочет

---

**Про индексы**

Во-первых, `post_id` — скорей всего первичный ключ (поправьте, если не так) в `post`, так что индекс для него и так всегда создаётся неявно.

Во-вторых, запрос в данном виде (если убрать `LIMIT 1000`) всегда будет требовать полного перебора записей в `post_phones`. Индекс тут ни чем не поможет, а с `LIMIT`'ом всё будет зависеть от данных — может и уменьшить на каком-то наборе (например если первая 1000 просмотренных записей подошла под условия), а может и увеличить (1000 искомых строк оказалась в самом конце таблицы). Так что в среднем и худшем случае время выполнения запроса будет `O(N*log(M))`, где `N` и `M` — размеры `post` и `post_id` соответственно.

Comment: посмотрите еще разок на код запроса который вы привели. И прочитайте еще раз задачу автора, он не сможет создать внешний ключ, поскольку значения отсутствуют в справочной, он как раз и выбирает те строки из таблицы данных, которым нет соответствия в справочной.

Comment: @teran, я написал, что их нужно будет предварительно удалить или установить в `NULL`...

Comment: вопрос бы о том, как эти записи найти. а не что делать дальше

Comment: @teran, вопрос о том, что запрос их ищущий у OP'а есть, но работает медленно... а нормального простого способа ускорить его работу принципиально нет, так что придётся или менять структуру БД и идти на компромиссы, или использовать что-то более хитрое вроде сохранения дополнительных данных тригерами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, "Перед добавлением ограничения все такие записи надо предварительно удалить или установить в NULL." Этот пункт возвращает нас к моему вопросу, сейчас сервер очень грузится при моём запросе, чтоб удалить, сначала надо найти ВСЁ. Или я что-то не правильно понял в этом пункте?

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха, всё так, но за несколько минут должен всё сделать... хотя бы один раз придётся всё перебрать — от этого не уйти... добавление индекса или ограничения займёт не меньше времени... и конечно помни, если работаешь с реальной базой «think before you type»...